# How to upload a file on Android to PC over USB

Tags: android, usb, file-transfer

When the Android device is connected to PC over USB, we can transfer files between device and PC easily by Windows Explorer. If I want to upload a file within an Android app, for example, if I click a button, then some files under specific directory would be transferred from device to PC. That is to say how to do this by programming. Any suggestions.

Comment: answers are here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/240846/how-to-transfer-files-between-android-and-ubuntu